# How to find out the time complexity of any prog

Tags: time-complexity, execution-time

Can anyone help me to get the time complexity of this prog. ? here i have put 3 loop and each loop is dependent on the other one. I mean inner loop is dependent on top inner loop and top inner loop is dependent on outer loop .

```
public static String getLargestPallindrome(String str)
{   StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();  
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++) //outer loop
    { 
        for(int j=str.length()-1;j>i;j--)  //top inner loop
        {  
            for(int k=i;k<=j;k++){   // inner lopp
            s=s.append(str.charAt(k)+"");}
            System.out.println("substring is "+s); 
            System.out.println("hey sub string is "+s.toString()); checkPallindrome(s.toString());
            s=s.append("");  s=new StringBuffer();

        }

    }

    return  largestPallindrome;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to find time complexity by looking at the number of `for` loops used. You need to understand the code flow and calculate number of computations happened. In this case it is around `n*n*(n-1)/2` which makes the time complexity `O(n^3)` since the highest degree of the polynomial is `n^3`. Where `n` is the size of the string `str`

Comment: how you have calculated that 2ndtime its running n time only  and 3rd time it running (n-1)/2 .

Comment: I have given an input of length 4 "abcd" and it ran 6 time .  ex abcd i have given and generating the below string abcd ,abc,ab,bcd,bc, cd.

Comment: According to your ans. if i have given an input that have string length 4 , it would have run 4*4*4=64 time it should execute, but its not runnung 64 time its running only 6 time

Comment: While calculating time complexity you need to use variables and strip of all the constants. `n^2` and `(n^2)/1000` both have `O(n^2)` time complexity

Comment: In simple words, if you plot a graph for `n` against number of instructions executed, the equation of the graph represents the order

Answer (score 0):

Thats incorrect when you say it ran only 6 times.
Try putting putting print statments in each loop and you will come to know how many time it executes.

```
public static String getLargestPallindrome(String str)
{   StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();  
    for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++) //outer loop
    { 
        System.out.println("Foo");
        for(int j=str.length()-1;j>i;j--)  //top inner loop
        {  
            System.out.println("Bar");
            for(int k=i;k<=j;k++){   // inner lopp
            s=s.append(str.charAt(k)+"");}
            System.out.println("substring is "+s); 
            System.out.println("hey sub string is "+s.toString()); checkPallindrome(s.toString());
            s=s.append("");  s=new StringBuffer();

        }

    }

    return  largestPallindrome;

}
```

Comment: That is not an answer to the original question. Complexity of an algorithm is an complex topic. Although in the end, one wants to know how often something executes, what is asked here is more of a formular (typically N, N*log(N) or N²).